# What does "2/2" mean in a patient note?

Tags: terminology

I am reading a few patient notes and see `2/2` used several times, e.g.:

> - Unclear if 2/2 to aspiration
> - Recurrent UTIs and hosp. for urosepsis - thought 2/2 to chronic indwelling Foley catheter for neurogenic bladder.
> - Trach was placed because was unable to clear secretions on her own 2/2 to  respiratory weakness
> - Her decreased responsiveness was thought to be 2/2 to meningitis
> - pt has respiratory weakeness 2/2 to multiple sclerosis

What does `2/2` mean in a patient note?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Right Diagnoses. Com](http://www.rightdiagnosis.com/medical-dictionary/2-2.htm)

It means secondary to.

From your [question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5257/what-does-2-2-mean-in-a-patient-note):

> Patient has respiratory weakness **secondary to** multiple sclerosis

If you are looking for a more credible source, [this site](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2655910/) mentions that it means "secondary to."

[Meded.uscd.edu](https://meded.ucsd.edu/clinicalmed/abbreviation.htm) also mentions its meaning.

Comment: Thanks! `2/2 to` is therefore a [RAS syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt True! Maybe I should add that to the answer. It seems to add something.